# undefined reference mentions non existant file of other user

Tags: c++, build, cmake, linker

I am trying to build the example program of libtins library.
I have another working project on the machine which uses this library so I created a new executable project in clion
and copied the lib tins folder from the other project to my new project.

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(cpp_pcap_read)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories(tins/include)
include_directories(tins/lib)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

add_executable(cpp_pcap_read ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(cpp_pcap_read
        pcap
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tins/lib/libtins.a)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <tins/tins.h>

using namespace Tins;

size_t counter(0);


bool count_packets(const Packet &pkt) {
    counter++;

    return true;
}

int main() {

    FileSniffer sniffer("/tmp/some_pcap_file.pcap");
    sniffer.sniff_loop(count_packets);

    return 0;
}
```

Build produces:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -I/home/vagrant/research/cpp-pcap-read/tins/include -I/home/vagrant/research/cpp-pcap-read/tins/lib  -g   -std=gnu++1y -o CMakeFiles/cpp_pcap_read.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/vagrant/research/cpp-pcap-read/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/cpp_pcap_read
/home/vagrant/clion-2016.3/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script  CMakeFiles/cpp_pcap_read.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /usr/bin/c++ -g CMakeFiles/cpp_pcap_read.dir/main.cpp.o -o ../bin/cpp_pcap_read -lpcap ../tins/lib/libtins.a
../tins/lib/libtins.a(sniffer.cpp.o): In function `~BaseSniffer':
/home/userx/tmp/libtins/src/sniffer.cpp:62: undefined reference to `pcap_close'
```

What did I do wrong?

Why does it mentions this path (`/home/userx/tmp/libtins/src/sniffer.cpp`) which is not on my machine nor that user (userx)?

Comment: That's the name of the source that was used to produce the `../tins/lib/libtins.a` file you're using.

Comment: It's possible that it is `chroot`ing?

Comment: Swap linking order: `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tins/lib/libtins.a pcap`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, amazing so much time wasted for such a simple fix. Thanks